# How can I get a html tag's value on React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, refs

I'm currently developing a function of the price tab by using React. The main function of these components is to let user add one of these classes price into  shopping cart .The problem is how Can I get a HTML tag's html string?
my sample code is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class ProductPage extends React.Component{
  let Data = {
    classA: 60,
    classB: 70,
    classC: 80
  };
  render(){
    return(
     <PriceTab priceData={Data}/>
    )
  }
}

class PriceTab extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
       super()
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }
    handleClick(event){
       let dom = ReactDOM.findDomNode(this.refs.priceA);
       console.log(dom.value)// got undefined.
     }
    render(){
        return()
               <div>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceA">{this.props.priceData.classA}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceB">{this.props.priceData.classB}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceC">{this.props.priceData.classC}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               </div>
       }
}

ReactDOM.Render(<ProductPage/> ,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Also are there any way to bind one button event detecting all of the values ?
Many thanks for any help ...

Comment: priceA is not an input field , so you can not get value of a li element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the value directly from an `li` element as `value` attribute is restricted to the `input` fields. What you can do is bind the handleClick function with the value.

```
class PriceTab extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
       super()
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
     }
    handleClick(value, event){
       console.log(value)   //here you will get the value of the li element
     }
    render(){
        return()
               <div>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceA">{this.props.priceData.classA}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.priceData.classA)}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceB">{this.props.priceData.classB}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.priceData.classB)}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               <ul>
                    <li ref="priceC">{this.props.priceData.classC}</li>
                    <li><button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.priceData.classC)}>Check Out</li>
               </ul>
               </div>
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this , and I set ID for each button then set the handleClick as follow:
    
    handleClick(value,event){
    let btnId = event.target.id;
    //do things........
    }
    
then the function can determine which button called this function.