# How to pass tag id to to onClick function in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass id of th tag `<th id='1' onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>` to on click function. Suppose i want to print the id of `<th>` in `click()` function console.log.
here is the code-

```
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th id='name' onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Name</th>
    <th id='phone' onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Phone number</th>
    <th id='email' onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Email</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

the click() function-

```
click(){
console.log('the clicked id is:') //here i want the id
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by id exactly? name should be printed on clicking Name th tag?

Comment: `onClick={this.click.bind(this,  'phone')}` then `onclick(id){console.log(id)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a html tag's value on React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732791/how-can-i-get-a-html-tags-value-on-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind takes arguments

```
this.click.bind(this, 'phone')

click(phone) {
  // ...
}
```

or use es6 arrow functions

```
onClick={() => this.click('phone')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const headers = [
  { id: 'name', label: 'Name' },
  { id: 'phone', label: 'Phone' },
  { id: 'Email', label: 'Name' },
]

const ab = (
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {headers.map(doc => (
        <th onClick={() => { this.click(doc.id) }}>{doc.label}</th>
      ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<tr>
  <th id='name' onClick={this.foo}>Name</th>
  <th id='phone' onClick={this.foo}>Phone number</th>
  <th id='email' onClick={this.foo}>Email</th>
</tr>
```

The onclick function

```
   foo=(e)=> {
     console.log(e.target.id);
   }
```