# React read value of button clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if this topic it's probably a copy of another one, but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong with my code + i'm really new to react. I tried several solutions but none of them worked. I will put here some of the post that i read:

- [React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)
- [How do I get the id of a button that was clicked? ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846915/how-do-i-get-the-id-of-a-button-that-was-clicked-reactjs)
- [How to pass tag id to to onClick function in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44406791/how-to-pass-tag-id-to-to-onclick-function-in-react)

***Problem***

I need to console.log the string inside `value` with handleInput

***Code***

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import Screen from './screen';
import './keyboard.css'

class NumberKeyboard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            operations: []
        }

    }

handleInput(props) {
    const buttonValue= this.props.value;
    console.log(buttonValue)
}


    render() {


        return (
            <div className="keyboard">
                <div className="column"></div>
                <div className="column">
                    <div className="keyboardRow roundBorder" value={"example"} onClick={() => this.handleInput('value')}>
                        <Screen className="crystalScreen"></Screen>
                        <Button value="clear" >C</Button> 
                        <Button value="±">±</Button>
                        <Button value=".">.</Button>
                        <Button value="">+</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="keyboardRow">
                        <Button value="clear">1</Button>
                        <Button value="2">2</Button>
                        <Button value="3">3</Button>
                        <Button value="-">-</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="keyboardRow">
                        <Button value="4">4</Button>
                        <Button value="5">5</Button>
                        <Button value="6">6</Button>
                        <Button value="*">X</Button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="keyboardRow lastRow">
                        <Button value="7">7</Button>
                        <Button value="8">8</Button>
                        <Button value="9">9</Button>
                        <Button value="%">÷</Button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="column"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NumberKeyboard;
```

i tried several attempts to solve it but every time the max result that i had it was the sadly undefined or an error.

--------------------------- UPDATE -------------------------

Due to visits of these post i want to give a little update and set an example based on hooks too:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import KeyboardRow from 'src/components/keyboardRow'; /* ideally this
 should contain the buttons element. i'm writing in this way just to stay 
 closer to the initial question */  

function NumberKeyboard() {
  const [selectedNumber, setSelectedNumber] = useState(0);

  const selectNumber = numberSelected => {
       setSelectedNumber(numberSelected)
  }

  return (
  <>
    <KeyboardRow >
       <Button onClick={selectNumber} value="7">7</Button>
       <Button onClick={selectNumber} value="8">8</Button>
       <Button onClick={selectNumber} value="9">9</Button>
    </KeyboardRow >
    <div>{selectedNumber}<div>
  </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are sending and receiving data in a wrong way. First, you need to use `onClick={this.handleInput}` or `onClick={(e) => this.handleInput(e,'value')}` instead of `onClick={() => this.handleInput('value')}` because you are sending `'value'` string in function.

```
<div className="keyboardRow roundBorder" value={"example"} onClick={e => this.handleInput(e, "value")} >
```

And then receive in following ways:

```
handleInput(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

You ca check the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxk4qm0yzq).

Comment: Can i ask a little thing ? Just to be sure that I really understand what you wrote ( because yeah, it's work ): onClick={e => this.handleInput(e, "value")} the " e " stand for the children button that i click ?

Comment: e is the event that is generated based on your click for the current element

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your buttons don't currently do anything when clicked, so what we're going to need to do is add an onClick to each of your buttons: `<Button onClick={this.handleInput} value="clear">C</Button>`.

This will pass the event to `handleInput`.

To get the value of the button clicked we can do:

```
handleInput(el) {
    console.log(el.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `event` object. Something like:

```
    handleInput = e => {
      const buttonValue = e.target.value;
      console.log(buttonValue);
      //some logic
}
```

And then you could add the method on the onClick event, passing the `event` object as well.

```
   onClick = {this.handleInput}
```

Answer (score 2):

- In handleInput function you were passing the "props" but using using "this.props"
- onClick should be there for every button
- Should not pass the string 'value' rather do this "onClick={(e) => this.handleInput(e)}"
- you can access with event.target.value