# recover data from an onClick() for an image tag

Tags: reactjs

## Hi I have an array of cat images which I recovered from Giphy api.

[image]

## What I want to do is click on the image and console.log the url associated with the image.

The below code is what I tried.

All that happen as soon as I hit the search button
console.log showed 25 undefined items.

So I think i'm passing information wrong, and it's detecting onCLick outside of the div

[image]

```
import React from "react";

function handleClick(props) {
  console.log(props.gif);
}

const UserItem = props => {
  return (
    <div className="column">
      <img
        onClick={handleClick(props.gif)}
        alt=""
        src={props.gif}
        className="ui image"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: `onClick={() => handleClick(props.gif)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a minor mistake, pay attention that `onClick` prop accepts a "pointer" to a function, in your code, you are invoking `handleClick` and it returns `undefined`, therefore, your code is not working.

You can change your handler to get the clicked element `src` attribute by accessing the click event.

```
import React from "react";

function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.target.src);
}

const UserItem = props => {
  return (
    <div className="column">
      <img
        onClick={handleClick}
        alt=""
        src={props.gif}
        className="ui image"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserItem;
```

Comment: I literally just found this answer 30 seconds ago here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498281/react-read-value-of-button-clicked?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for the help you beat me to it